# mysql delete from group by after 2nd element

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
ID     Friend
John    Rita
John    Jack
Jack    Rita
John    Tom
Rita    John
```

I want to write a query where I delete all `ID`'s who has more than 2 element. In other words I keep for each `ID` maximum 2 `friends`.

I have tried with a `group by` or somethin like that, but I don't now exactly how I have to do the delete.

The result must be:

```
ID  Friend
John    Rita
John    Jack
Jack    Rita
Rita    John
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be joining on the grouped table and deleting all records where the join could not be established

```
delete t1
from your_table t1
left join 
(
   select id, min(friend) as f1, max(friend) as f2
   from your_table
   group by id
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
    and t1.friend in (t2.f1, t2.f2)
where t2.id is null
```

The inner select gets 2 friends for each ID.

Comment: and if we had to keep 5 friends?

Comment: Then you have to use a different solution. But that was not the question.